# Skscene transitioning in Swift

Tags: swift, skscene

In essence, I have a menu scene and level scene and I want to be able to transition back and forth. If you look here you can see the first present scene which starts off showing the menu.

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        let testLevel = LevelMenu()
        testLevel.size = self.view.frame.size
        testLevel.initializeMenu(NumberOfLevels: 6, Restricted: true, MenuNumber: 1)
        testLevel.scaleMode = .fill
        view.presentScene(testLevel)
        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
```

(LevelMenu is a custom class which extends SKScene, initialize menu is a method which I use to set up the specifics of the scene.)

Now inside the LevelMenu class if a couple conditions are met the following code is called to go into a level.

```
if let view = self.view as SKView? {
        view.presentScene(currentLevel)
    }
```

(currentLevel is a variable which stores the current Level object.)

Also, when the levels are set up they have the same code as the menu when its set up.

```
let TempLevel = Level()
TempLevel.size = self.size
TempLevel.setUp(package: menuNumber, numberInPackage: i, locked: 
   restricted, menu: self)
TempLevel.name = "Package \(menuNumber), Level \(i)"
TempLevel.scaleMode = .fill
levels.append(TempLevel)
```

(Level is another custom SKScene, setUp() is a method which sets it up, and levels is an array which holds all the levels.)

To transition back to the menu I call this code again just with the menu which has been passed through to the class.

`if let view = self.view as SKView? {
            view.presentScene(currentLevel)
        }`

This is the issue: When I call the transition inside the menu to go to a level it works perfectly. Transitions animates works perfectly fine; however, when I call the presentScene() to go back, it will print out the text I put in the viewDidAppear() except it still shows the level Skscene and the level Skscene still has working buttons.

I tried removing scenes from their parents and it seems to not work and from what I have read be a bad idea. I theorize that the menu scene is loaded the whole time and just blocked and when I call presentScene it says "hey I'm here." but fails to realize I want it up front. If there could be some way to stop presenting the level scene and just have the menu show up that would be great since once you finish a level it shouldn't just sit around.

Thank you in advance for all help offered.

Comment: anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Through more investigation and debugging it seems as if the menu is being loaded again but for some reason, the graphics are not changing.

Answer (score 0):

So though more investigation and debugging I found out that the scene was actually being loaded but for some reason was not being displayed. After playing around with the visual settings I thought about making sure the size of the scene was the proper size and I found that by setting the size of the menu before going back it now shows the menu.
I hope this question helps someone out there who ever encounters a similar issue, thanks internet for nothing.